# Issue with connecting to MariaDB via docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am setting up 2 similar projects with Docker. They use the same images: wordpress:php7.4-apache and mariadb:10.3.39. I am using different ports for both projects, just to be able to run both project simultaneously : first MariaDB runs on 3306, second MariaDB runs on 3307. The error also happens if I use the same port for both projects, and run one single project at a time.

Connection to MariaDB does not work for first project, but works fine for second. Both projects have the exact same configuration!

Here is config for project 1:

.env file

```
# .env
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project1
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=database
MYSQL_USER=docker
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mariadb:10.3.39
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - my_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php7.4-apache
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}

volumes:
  my_db:
```

here is config for project 2:

.env file

```
# .env
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project2
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=database
MYSQL_USER=docker
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mariadb:10.3.39
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - my_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php7.3-apache
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}

volumes:
  my_db:
```

When I try to connect to MariaDB in project 1, I get this error:

> docker exec -it 609f7807c859 mysql -udocker -psecret -e 'show databases;'
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'docker'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Whereas in project 2, it works:

> docker exec -it 484a719c2e6e mysql -udocker -psecret -e 'show databases;'

```
----------------------
| Database           |
----------------------
| database           |
| information_schema |
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not related to the problem you have, (already answerd), but why are you using such an old Wordpress and MariaDB version? Earliest supported [Wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) is `php-8.1-apache` and [mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) 10.4 (for the next few months before it goes end of support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have done `docker-compose up` with different credentials.

When you do first `docker-compose up` volumes is created and user `MYSQL_USER` with password `MYSQL_PASSWORD`, and even after calling `docker-compose down` and then changing password in `.env` and calling again `docker-compose up` password will be the same. To resolve it you can manually remove `volume` or just call `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml down --volumes` it will remove also volumes(so if need dump your data before doing it) and recreate it using `docker-compose up`

Comment: Bravo! that was it. THANK YOU!