# MariaDB docker image trouble connecting with cli

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have created a docker container using the official image. I have tried several methods to connect but I get the below warning.
I have also tried to use other examples from the image documentation but none of them is working.
https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb

`$ mariadb --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root --password`

`$ mariadb --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3306 --user=root --password`

2024-01-23T06:43:39.612639215Z 2024-01-23  6:43:39 3 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.25.0.1' (using password: NO)

```
mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
        - '3306:3306'
    environment:
        MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
```

Some Logs from the MariaDB container

```
   Some logs from the MariaDB container:
    2024-01-23 06:43:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.288290873Z 2024-01-23 06:43:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.292507092Z 2024-01-23 06:43:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.496575650Z 2024-01-23 06:43:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.517061698Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259 as process 1
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.526481981Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.527498693Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.527507199Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.527539363Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.527880276Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.528617763Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.536273814Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.543930878Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.547410093Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=47629
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.604918093Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.604933398Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.605217501Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.605249473Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.606086442Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 47629; transaction id 14
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.606192280Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.606235965Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.606269115Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.608103966Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240123  6:43:30
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.611498837Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.611511280Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.612304959Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@%' has a wrong 'access' value 0xffffffffff (allowed mask is 0x7fffffffff, version_id=110301)
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.613773685Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    2024-01-23T06:43:30.614026109Z 2024-01-23  6:43:30 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
```

Comment: Try to set `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` env in `environment` block with desired password.

Comment: Tried everything, nothing works

Comment: If the data is already initialized, then all env variables involved no-longer have an effect. This startup logs isn't an initialization. `docker-compose down -v` removes volumes. They might be created even without a explicit volume.

Comment: Where do you execute the `mariadb` login command? Inside pod or Outside host machine.

Comment: "[Warning] 'user' entry 'root@%' has a wrong 'access' value 0xffffffffff" version_id=110301)" looks like you started a 11.3.1-rc instance and when back to 11.2.2. Checked - once this happens that user has no access.

Comment: @danblack `docker compose down -v` worked! looks like changes were not taking effect with just docker compose up. Feel free to write an answer

Comment: I wrote about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77863490/21863762) overall default behavior is of docker-compose is to prevent losing data accidentally, so `volumes` are not removed just by calling `down` command and you have to explicitly say that you want to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB has a volume `/var/lib/mysql` that is assigned by compose.

Data is already initialized, then all env variables involved no-longer have an effect. This startup logs isn't an initialization.

`docker-compose down -v` removes volumes.

They are be created by compose even without a explicit volume declaration.

Also `[Warning] 'user' entry 'root@%' has a wrong 'access' value 0xffffffffff" version_id=110301)` looks like a 11.3.1-rc instance was started, and then the verision got changed back to 11.2.2.

I checked the [source code](https://github.com/mariaDB/server/commit/e26056e181e9#diff-df544694418bef1c4bc6cdc5211ca133e7ad4d31901f16d0fdee8df6e4debe89R1526), once this happens that user has no access.